# Why myFunction and &myFunction have different addresses for cimport customized functions?

Tags: c, cython

In `another.pyx`, I have

```
cdef double myadd(double a, double b):
    cdef double c = a + b
    return c
```

In `another.pxd`, I have

```
cdef double myadd(double a, double b)
```

If I run this:

```
from another cimport myadd
from libc.math cimport exp
from libc.stdio cimport sprintf
def test():
    cdef char s[80]
    sprintf(s, "%p", <void *> myadd)
    print s
    sprintf(s, "%p", <void *> &myadd)
    print s
    sprintf(s, "%p", <void *> exp)
    print s
    sprintf(s, "%p", <void *> &exp)
    print s


0x7f5ccc638130
0x7f5ccc62d5e0
0x32b9622f90
0x32b9622f90
```

Why is `myadd` and `&myadd` different? It turns out if I use `&myadd` version and assign it to a function pointer, the program will crash without warning if I call the function pointer with arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the .c that Cython creates, you will see that what it declares is:

```
/* Module declarations from 'another' */
static double (*__pyx_f_7another_myadd)(double, double); /*proto*/
```

And then prints (a lot omitted in between):

```
  sprintf(__pyx_v_s, __pyx_k_p, ((void *)__pyx_f_7another_myadd));
  sprintf(__pyx_v_s, __pyx_k_p, ((void *)(&__pyx_f_7another_myadd)));
```

`__pyx_f_7another_myadd` is a pointer to a function. If you make it point to some particular function, it will contain it's address in `__pyx_f_7another_myadd`, but the adress of `__pyx_f_7another_myadd` itself (i.e. `&__pyx_f_7another_myadd` remains the same). Since it is true that function declaration themselves ar pointers to functions, maybe a plain C++ example it can be seen what's happening:

```
#include <iostream>

int funcion(int a, int b)
{

  std::cout << a+b << std::endl;
}

int (*func) (int,int);

int main()
{
  std::cout << (void*) funcion << std::endl;
  std::cout << (void*) &funcion << std::endl;

  func = funcion;

  std::cout << (void*) func << std::endl;
  std::cout << (void*) &func << std::endl;
}

0x400886
0x400886
0x400886
0x601198
```

Here `funcion` was declared as a function itself, so it is its own pointer (hence the two equal initial adresses). On the other hand, `func` is a function pointer: it stores `funcion` adress (the third line), but it has an adress of its own (hence the different fourth line).

Something like `(&func) (1,2)` won't compile since this expression is not a function call, but `(func) (1,2)` is, and works.

Comment: Very good explanation, I didn't expect the name `myadd` binds to `__pyx_f_7another_myadd` which is a pointer to the actual function.